# Movie: main character sees the time left in a person's life on their forehead

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have been trying for ages to find the title of a movie where the main character can see the remainder of a person's life counting down on their forehead.  (Note, specifically not their arm.)

It is is not *The Frightened*, it is not *In Time*, nor a short movie or manga.
The closest I've found is *White Noise: The Light*. But it's not that either.
Also it's not the Nickelback song "Savin me". But the movie is exactly like that song.

Comment: You mention the number on the forehead, but also that it is "exactly like" the Nickelback song (which depicts the number above the head). Do you know if it was on or above the head?

Also - do you recall if the main character (that you've mentioned in comments was male) acted on the numbers in any way? Saved people? Warned them?

Comment: @LazyTitan - In roughly which year did you first see this movie, and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: For reference, the 2015 Doctor Who episode [Face The Raven](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4701538/) has a tattoo-like number counting down on the back of a character's neck.

Answer (score 11):

It's not a movie but a TV episode, but the 2009 episode "[The Future's So Bright](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1541338/)" (season 6, episode 9) of [*Medium*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0412175/) has the title character find a pair of glasses that show her a count of the number of days people have left to live on their foreheads.

[image: Character with a number "2" on his forehead]

A [review on IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw2211476/) explains these are a lifetimer countdown:

> The Lina Wertmuller-styled white rimmed sun glasses that Arquette dons in a very flimsy early plot twist (resolved convincingly in the final reel as to their source) let her see white digits superimposed on people's foreheads, not unlike the way place names and building names are super-ed in each episode of FRINGE. Younger people have numbers like 20100 or 15500, but when she sees both suspects and colleagues with a big 1 or 2 on their noggins, it becomes obvious that she can perceive how many days each person has left to live.

Comment: Its exactly like that but, I remember the main character of the movie being a male. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

When you said it's not "The Frightened" (I couldn't find a movie matching that title), we're you referring to the 1996 Comedy/Horror, "The Frighteners"?

If not, it fits all the details you provided.
[The Frighteners - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Frighteners)

Michael J Fox (male lead) plays a character named Frank Bannister who gains the power to see ghosts after the death of his wife.

He later finds himself facing off against a "Grim Reaper"-like entity who kills people after marking their foreheads with a glowing number that only Frank can see. Example:

[image: Here is a screencap of a marked victim]

It does somewhat resemble the glowing numbers from "Savin' Me" and fits all the details you've provided (unless this is the movie you were referring too and already discounted it).

Comment: Except in this movie the number wasn't how much time they had left but which victim of the reaper they were (the woman in the picture was the intended 41st victim, for example).

Answer (score 7):

Unlikely to be confused with a full length movie, but there is a **Korean short film "[Numbers](https://www.shortoftheweek.com/2014/07/23/numbers/)"** by Robert Hloz starring a male protagonist who can see number *above* the heads of other people.This is understood to be a death timer. The protagonist meets another person who can see the same.

[image]